List of google calendar rooms in organisation
I am creating a tool that would let customer see the rooms that are booked on a map.

A customer can associate a room to a room in google workspace.
When customer wants to associate a room I want to display a dropdown of rooms that are present in google organisation.

What is the correct way to fetch the list of rooms?
Should I be using the admin-sdk, service account or use the members account to retrieve the rooms (as far as I researched the last option is not possible)?
If I use the service account, wouldn't it mean that the customer (another organisation) should somehow add the my account to their organisation?

SUGGESTION:
You can try this sample Google Apps Script code to list all calendar resources using Admin SDK Directory API:
function myFunction() {

  var list = AdminDirectory.Resources.Calendars.list('my_customer');
  for(item in list.items){
    console.log(list.items[item].resourceName);
  }

}

Sample logs:

Just make sure that AdminDirectory service is added on your Apps Script project like so:

You can also use the API Explorer here in this article for resources.calendars.list
References:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars/list
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Thanks for the response! So using this 'apps script' approach, I suppose my account should be added as an admin in the customer workspace? Or I can use any user credentials that is able to see the rooms but just fetch it via the 'app script' using the users credentials?

@MarkusRidziauskas Yes that is correct, this can be achieved using authorization from an admin account for that particular Google Workspace. Same goes with other options
